# Flutter Error Firebase User ReauthenticateWithCredential

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am developing an app in flutter and I'll need to Re Authenticate user but I am getting below error

```
I/flutter (14968): Error: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null
I/flutter (14968): Receiver: null
I/flutter (14968): Tried calling: []("user")
```

Below is the code i am using to re authenticate user

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  print("User Email: ${user.email}");
  AuthCredential authCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(
    email: user.email,
    password: _oldPassController.text,
  );
  print("Auth Credential: ${authCredential.toString()}");
  user.reauthenticateWithCredential(authCredential).then((result) {
    print("Success: $result");
  }).catchError((error) {
    print("Error: $error");
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    if (error is PlatformException) {
      PlatformException exception = error;
      showAlertDialog(context, exception.message);
    } else {
      showAlertDialog(context, error.toString());
    }
  });
```

Comment: I just ran into this problem; it appears to be a known bug: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1085

Answer (score 2):

## *March 2023*

You can re-authenticate a user as follows:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
currentUser?.reauthenticateWithCredential(
    EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        email: currentUser!.email!,
        password: 'password',
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fix for the actual problem (I think it's actually a Firebase-to-Flutter-project connection problem), but I have a workaround that works for me. 
I simply use signInWithEmailAndPassword() in place of reauthenticateWithCredential(), and it seems to be working fine. Like so:

```
    AuthResult authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = authResult.user;
```

After calling the signInWithEmailAndPassword(), the user is re-authenticated because they've recently been logged in. 
Hope it's useful.